# Der Unterschied zwischen »Es kommt mit der Zeit« und »Es ist an der Zeit«

Tags: difference, preposition, phrase

> Auf dem Nachttisch die Pille,
>   Mordgedanken im Blick
>   und der Wünsche zu viele,
>   deine Sorgen, deine Sorgen sind dein Trick.
>
> Es ist an der Zeit,
>   dass du endlich begreifst,
>   dass du endlich verstehst,
>   dass es nicht nur um dich geht.

Das ist ein Teil des Westernhagen Liedes »Es ist an der Zeit«. Ich möchte gern wissen, ob sie die selbe Bedeutung haben. Hätte er auch »Es kommt mit der Zeit« statt »Es ist an der Zeit« sagen können?

Comment: Nein. *Es ist an der Zeit* ist eine lange, ältliche Form von *es ist Zeit*. Man kann bei diesem Ausdruck nicht nach "Es" fragen. Wogegen *es kommt mit der Zeit* die Frage nach dem "Es" erlaubt.

Answer (score 4):

Nein, die Bedeutung würde sich dabei grundlegend ändern. Zum vergleich  folgender fiktiven Dialog:

> >> Die Aussprache fällt mir immer noch schwer.
>   << Ach, das kommt mit der Zeit.

Bringt zum Ausdruck, dass nur genügend Zeit vergehen muss bis etwas *(automatisch)* eintrifft/passiert

> >> Die Aussprache fällt mir immer noch schwer
>   << Es ist an der Zeit, dass du das lernst.

Hingegen würde zum Ausdruck bringen, dass bereits genug Zeit vergangen ist (und jetzt der Zeitpunkt gekommen ist).

Übertragen auf den Satz könnte man diesen in etwa wie folgt interpretieren.

> > Es kommt mit der Zeit, dass du begreifst, dass du verstehst, dass es nicht nur um dich geht

*Es braucht Zeit zu begreifen, dass ...* oder
*Mit dem Alter begreift man, dass ...* bzw.
*Wenn man älter wird lernt man zu begreifen, dass ...*

Das klingt nicht nur merkwürdig, sondern drückt auch nicht mehr, wie *es ist an der Zeit* die Meinung des Sprechenden aus, dass jetzt ein bestimmter Zeitpunkt für etwas gekommen sei.

Answer (score 0):

### Es kommt mit der Zeit

Diese Phrase bedeutet, dass etwas noch nicht da ist, dass es also noch nicht existiert bzw. noch nicht der Fall ist. Es bedeutet aber auch, dass es in der Zukunft kommen wird. Es kommt gemeinsam mit der Zeit. Wenn »neue Zeit« (also die Zukunft) kommt, kommt auch das, worauf sich »es« bezieht.

Wir blicken hier also in die Zukunft und machen eine Vorhersage über ein Ereignis (eine Zustandsänderung), das (meist ohne unser Zutun) in der Zukunft geschehen wird.

---

### Es ist an der Zeit

Das bedeutet, dass das, worauf sich »es« bezieht, mit einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt verknüpft ist, an dem *es* erledigt werden soll. Dieser Zeitpunkt lag vor einigen Stunden, Wochen, Jahren noch in der Zukunft. Aber inzwischen ist Zeit vergangen (Zeit ist gekommen), und der Zeitpunkt, an dem *es* erledigt werden soll, ist nun Gegenwart geworden. *Es* sollte also, gemäß ursprünglichem Plan, genau jetzt erledigt werden. Man muss nicht länger darauf warten, dass der optimale Zeitpunkt für die Erledigung irgend wann einmal kommt. Dieser Zeitpunkt ist jetzt da.

Wir betrachten hier also die Gegenwart und leiten aus den gegenwärtigen Gegebenheiten die Notwendigkeit ab, jetzt etwas zu tun.

Comment: Sicher, dass sich das *Es* in »Es ist an der Zeit«, auf etwas bezieht und nicht ein schlichtes Expletivum ist?

Comment: @Jan: Ich habe diesen Gedanken in Erwägung gezogen, bin aber der Meinung, dass das hier nicht zutrifft. Wenn jemand sagt »Es ist an der Zeit« dann ist damit immer gemeint, dass genau jetzt *etwas ganz bestimmtes* getan werden soll. Und dieses *ganz bestimmte Etwas* ist genau das, worauf sich das Wort »es« bezieht. Ein Expletivum bezieht sich gemäß Definition auf nichts, es füllt nur eine grammatische Lücke aus ohne selbst eine semantische Bedeutung zu haben. Das »es« in »Es ist an der Zeit« ist daher ein anderes »es« als z.B. jenes in »Es schneit«.